# dialog.dismiss method is not meaningful in AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

General `AlertDialog` with OK/Cancel buttons in android is as below.

```
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(QuestionViewActivity.this);
    dialog.setTitle("Write something");
    dialog.setView(layout);

    dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            try {
                postArticle(editText.getText().toString());
                dialog.dismiss();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException exception) {

            }
        }
    });
    dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog ad = dialog.create();
    ad.show();
```

I found that `dialog.dismiss();` method is not meaningful, so the dialog is closed even the method is commented. I assume that button click event in dialog calls dialog close command automatically.

is it true?

Comment: yes. You can prevent automatic dismiss of dialog by custom button click listener for dialog buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right. OnClick event of dialog buttons dialog got dismiss automatically. If you want dialog won't close automatically then you have to set it explicitly. like `dialog.setCancelable(false);`